# Passing wrapper like option on php array

Tags: php, wrapper

What I am trying to do here is that I am bulding php application but I want to have options.

Example :

```
   $options= array(
    'elementWrapper'=>'<div class="wrapper"></div>'
    );

    And passing it like :

    $myapp->options($options);
```

How to split this string elementWrapper like 2 variables : |

```
$elementWrapperStart - (<div class="wrapper">) and $elementWrapperEnd - (</div>);
```

Or maybe this won´t be a `div` in some cases to handle this automatically and to wrap the elements inside this passed element.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: usually just use the DOMDocument class and add child nodes to it… and then output the HTML at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Another array...

```
$options= array(
    'elementWrapper' => array(
        'start'=> '<div class="wrapper">', 
        'end'  => '</div>'
     )
);
```

Accessible as `$options['elementWrapper']['start']` and `$options['elementWrapper']['end']`:

```
$elementWrapperStart = $options['elementWrapper']['start'];
$elementWrapperEnd   = $options['elementWrapper']['end'];
```

Comment: I have thoughts of that but i need to make really simple so my users can understand. Its not for developers. The what my users will be is the complete div wrapper like i mentioned to my questions. Any other suggestio ?

Comment: Well, in that case you can split the string at `><` but it's a little risky.

Comment: Yeah its a little risky. i had that solution in my mind thats becuase i needed more simple solution

Comment: I don't think there's anything simpler than these two. Even for non-devs, this is pretty clear: `$options['elementWrapper']['start'] = '<div>'`, right?

Comment: You're welcome. Let's see if someone comes up with something better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62039/discussion-between-user2317735-and-shomz).

Answer (score 0):

As @bwoebi already pointed out you should most likely be using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) since using split or regular expressions is very error prone when parsing HTML strings.

```
// I´m just assuming your class looks something like this:
class MyApp {

    private $options;

    public function options($options) {

        if (isset($options['elementWrapper'])) {
            $dom = new DomDocument;
            $dom->loadHtml($options['elementWrapper']);
            $options['elementWrapper'] = $dom->documentElement;
        }   
        $this->options = $options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just pass a two element array:

```
$myapp->options(array(
  array(
     'start' => '<div class="wrapper">',
     'end'   => '</div>'
  )
));
```